# case statement not evaluated

Tags: haskell

If m2 and m are equal I want to do an IO operation (send out some stuff over the network) that returns nothing and update my map. I have crafted the following code and wonder (1) if this can be refactored into something less clunky (2) why my case expression that should send out the messages does not get evaluated or at least no messages do get send.

If I uncomment the code at the bottom then things do get send as I want to, but of course it is then send out disregarding what the value of m2 is.

```
main = withSocketsDo $ do
     s <- socket AF_INET Datagram defaultProtocol
     (q, m) <- newRq
     let m2 = appendMsg "first" key m
         _ = case m2 of        
                   val | m2 == m -> do let Just messages = Map.lookup ("192.168.1.1", 4711) m in sendq s (B.pack $ unwords messages) "192.168.1.1" 4711
         (q4, m4) = case m2 of 
                   val | m2 == m -> deleteRec key q m2
                       | otherwise -> (q, m2)
     --let Just messages = Map.lookup ("192.168.1.1", 4711) m
     --sendq s (B.pack $ unwords messages) "192.168.1.1" 4711
```

I know that _ is not defined for all cases where m2 and m are not equal, but sendq returns `IO ()` and I could not think of something sensible to add here for `| otherwise ->` that would return the same type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two lines of code starting with `_ = case m2 of` do exactly nothing! This is because the bound value `_` never gets evaluated, because it is not used (or even mentioned) anywhere else.

What you are looking for is, I guess, the function `when` from `Control.Monad`. It has type `Monad m => Bool -> m () -> m()`; you could use it as follows:

```
 when (m == m2) (send the messages ...)
```

but you would have to use it outside the `let` block, i.e. as part of the main `do` expression.

One more thing, your code:

```
     (q4, m4) = case m2 of 
               val | m2 == m -> deleteRec key q m2
                   | otherwise -> (q, m2)
```

can be simplified to:

```
     (q4, m4) = if (m2 == m) then deleteRec key q m2 else (q, m2)
```

Comment: Thanks, works for me. What happens in this case 'when (m == m2) (fun1)' w the return value of fun1? Is it always ignored?

Comment: @JFritsch, the return value must be `()` for `when` to work, so it's not useful anyways. But you could say that it is ignored.

Comment: @JFritsch: yes, that's right! It's also about the only sensible thing that `when` can actually do, if you think about the type a bit. `when` is defined like `when condition action = if condition then action else return ()`, and there's not much else that can go in place of the `return ()` part. If you want more control over what happens to the result of `fun1`, you should consider writing your own `if ... then ... else ...` statement.

Comment: OP, think of a value with type `m ()` as an action that we _could_ potentially decide to execute.  The `let` statement in your original code will define an action, but it won't actually _execute_ it; you'll have to execute it in the `do` statement for it to be processed.